# UIButton.Configuration causes a fade in animation for changing the button image color

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibutton

Previously I had a custom `UIButton` class I used for some buttons that behave similarly to a segmented control (i.e. they can be toggled on/off).

I'm attempting to replace the old code to use the new `UIButton.Configuration` config property. But in doing so, the button UI behaviour has subtly changed.

Previously when changing the button image color it changed immediately, without animation. But now, for certain transitions, **there is a slight animation where the new color fades in**.

It seems like when it's transitioning to `isHighlighted` to `true` or `isSelected` to `false`, there is no animation, but for `isHighlighted` going to `false` or `isSelected` going to `true`, it animates the new image color fading in.

---

Here is the old button code, with no image color fade in animation:

```swift
class MyOldButton: UIButton {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) { fatalError() }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupUI()
    }
    
    private var customColor: UIColor {
        switch (isSelected, isHighlighted) {
        case (true, false):
            return .red
        case (true, true):
            return .green
        case (false, false):
            return .blue
        case (false, true):
            return .yellow
        }
    }
    
    private func setupUI() {
        clipsToBounds = true
        adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
        adjustsImageWhenDisabled = false
        
        tintAdjustmentMode = .normal
        
        tintColor = customColor
    }
    
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            tintColor = customColor
        }
    }
    
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            tintColor = customColor
        }
    }
    
}
```

---

And the new button code, which introduces a fade in animation when the image color is changed (but only for `isHighlighted` to `false` and `isSelected` to `true`):

```swift
class MyNewButton: UIButton {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) { fatalError() }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupUI()
    }
    
    private var customColor: UIColor {
        switch (isSelected, isHighlighted) {
        case (true, false):
            return .red
        case (true, true):
            return .green
        case (false, false):
            return .blue
        case (false, true):
            return .yellow
        }
    }
    
    private func setupUI() {
        clipsToBounds = true
        tintAdjustmentMode = .normal
        backgroundColor = .clear
        changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true
        
        var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
        config.imagePlacement = .top
        configuration = config
        
        configurationUpdateHandler = { [weak self] button in
            guard let self else { return }
            var config = button.configuration
            config?.baseForegroundColor = self.customColor
            button.configuration = config
        }
    }
    
}
```

---

I can't figure what is causing that image color fade in animation, or how to remove it.

**Does anyone know?**

---

### UPDATE

Thank you to Fogmeister in the comments for a suggestion that removes the animation.

Here is the updated `configurationUpdateHandler` code:

```swift
        configurationUpdateHandler = { [weak self] button in
            guard let self else { return }
            var config = button.configuration
            config?.baseForegroundColor = self.customColor
            
            // The fix 
            UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                button.configuration = config
            }
        }
```

I'm happy it can be shipped now!  But still curious where that color fade in animation was coming from.

Comment: Just a brief thought for now. Have you tried wrapping the change in `UIView.withoutAnimation`? (I think that's what it's called). Give that. atry.

Comment: Oh wow, that actually works. Thank you! I'll update the question with the now non-animating code.